# How to get locations's coordinates from Google Map

Tags: android

I have created a MapActivity in android studio for opening Google Map and that is working fine. But now I want to get location's coordinates when a location is selected (by tapping on the map), so how can I do that?

**Map.java**

```
package com.example.abc.project1;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        //GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.868664, 151.183194);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17.0f));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onMapReady` set a clickListener for you GoogleMap object.

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
```

Then you need to implement the `GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener` interface inside your activity. You will receive click events with clicked position like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    // do what you gotta do
}
```